# Why does variables substitution not work when using multiple env_files in docker-compose.yml?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to get a docker-compose file working with multiple `.env` files, and I'm not having any luck.  I'm trying to setup three `.env` files:

- global settings that are the same across all container instances
- environment-specific settings (stuff just for test or dev)
- local settings - overridable things that a developer might need to change in case they have conflicts with, say, a port number

My `docker-compose.yml` file looks like this:

```
version: '2'
services:
  db:
    env_file:
      - ./.env
      - ./.env.${ENV}
      - ./.env.local
    image: postgres
    ports:
      - ${POSTGRES_PORT}:5432
```

`.env` looks like this:

```
POSTGRES_USER=myapp
```

and the `.env.development` looks like this:

```
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=supersecretpassword
POSTGRES_HOST=localhost
POSTGRES_PORT=25432
POSTGRES_DB=myapp_development
```

`.env.local` doesn't exist in this case.

After running `ENV=development docker-compose up`, I receive the following output:

```
$ ENV=development docker-compose up
WARNING: The POSTGRES_PASSWORD variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARNING: The POSTGRES_DB variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARNING: The POSTGRES_PORT variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
services.db.ports is invalid: Invalid port ":5432", should be [[remote_ip:]remote_port[-remote_port]:]port[/protocol]
```

From that error message, it looks like none of my environment variables are being used.  I just upgraded to the newest available docker-compose as well - same errors:

```
$ docker-compose --version
docker-compose version 1.8.0-rc1, build 9bf6bc6
```

Any ideas here?  Would be nice to have a single `docker-compose.yml` that would work across multiple environments.

Comment: Rubber ducking here - I think the root issue is that i was expecting the environment variables declared in my .env file to be available within my docker-compose.yml.  They're not (or, at least, I don't believe they are).  I can remove the entire `environment` section from my docker-compose.yml, but I'm not sure how I'll handle port redirection at the moment.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? The docker-compose documents seem to imply that this is allowed but I am encountering the same issue. I guess I am not understanding how to do this.

Comment: I didn't get it working, but I also understand why it's not working - first, I didn't need the `environment` section at all, since the various `.env` files take care of that.  Second, the `docker-compose.yml` file won't read in the `env_file` settings - the settings in there are just passed along to the containers.  In my run, `POSTGRES_PORT` doesn't exist because it's not defined in my shell, regardless of the fact that it's in my `.env` file.

Answer (score 13):

In order to apply different/multiple env_files depending on the running environment, such as development/staging/production, I think a better way for docker-compose is to use multiple docker-compose yml files.

For example:

#### 1. Start with a base file that defines the canonical configuration for the services.

```
docker-compose.yml

web:
  image: example/my_web_app:latest
  env_file:
    - .env
```

#### 2. Add the override file for development, as its name implies, can contain configuration overrides for existing services or entirely new services.

docker-compose.override.yml

```
web:
  build: .
  volumes:
    - '.:/code'
  ports:
    - 8883:80
  env_file:
    - .env.dev
```

When you run `docker-compose up` it reads the overrides automatically.

#### 3. Create another override file for the production environment.

docker-compose.prod.yml

```
web:
  ports:
    - 80:80
  env_file:
    - .env.prod
```

To deploy with this production Compose file you can run

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.prod.yml up
```

#### Note

My Docker version:

```
$ docker -v
Docker version 18.06.1-ce, build e68fc7a

$ docker-compose -v
docker-compose version 1.22.0, build f46880fe
```

Reference: https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/

Comment: I think it's confusing to use the default compose .env file name as an env_file. The .env file in the CWD defines default environment variables available to compose, including COMPOSE_FILE, while the env_file list is used to define environment variables for the container.

Comment: You are right, you don't need to specify .env as an env_file in a docker compose yml file. It will be used by default, and variables defined there can be overridden.

Comment: Overriding does not seem to work on docker-compose v 3.8 and docker v20.10.2 - setting any environment variables via the compose file does not work at all now (for me).

Comment: Here in 2023, also finding that when calling `docker compose up -d` and using `docker-compose.override.yml` to pull in `.env.dev`, it won't override variables in `.env` with those in `.env.dev`.

Answer (score 7):

Keep in mind that there are 2 different environments where you are defining variables. The host machine where you are executing the docker-compose command, and the container itself (running the db service in your case).

Your `docker-compose.yml` file has access to your host's environment variables. Hence `ENV` is reachable from the `docker-compose` command, but not these in your `.env` files.

On the contrary, the value for `ENV` is not reachable inside the container, but all variables defined in your `.env` files will.

I don't know if you really need your `db` container to access the variables defined on your `.env.development`. But at least seem that your host machine needs to have the content of that file, so when the docker-compose command is called, the `POSTGRES_PORT` variable is defined.

To fix your specific problem you would need to define the environment variables on your host machine too, not only for the container. You could do something like this:

```
#Set for host
ENV=development

#Also sets the variables on the host 
source ./.env.$ENV

#POSTGRES_PORT defined in .env.development is used here
docker-compose up

#since env_file also contains .env.development, the variables will be reachable from the container.
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 7):

There is a misconception regarding the .env file and the env_file option in the docker-compose.yml, as it is very ambiguous. [Shin](https://github.com/shin-) points it out very nicely in the github issue [docker-compose doesn't use env_file](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/4001#issuecomment-251520659). I will just quote his summary:

> - Variable substitution in your docker-compose.yml file will be pulled (in decreasing order of priority) from your shell's environment and your .env file.
> - Variables available in your container are a combination of values found in your env_file files and values described in the environment section of the service.
> - Those are two entirely separate sets of features.

Comment: Very helpful answer. TL;DR: `.env` is for *compose*; `env_file` is for *containers*!

Answer (score -2):

while reading this page: https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/

and from my understanding, you should do the following:

for the global variables(that should not change) make an env file like so:

```
VAR1=VALUE1
VAR2=VALUE2
```

and for the others(that might change) you should add their name under environment in docker-compose.yml like this:

```
environment:
    - VAR1
    - VAR2
```

this will take the VAR1 and VAR2 values from the shell you are running docker-compose.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure that this is what I'm looking for - the issue I'm having is that i have `POSTGRES_PORT` defined in a `.env.test` file, but I want it to be used within my `docker-compose.yml` file when i start the container - that's just not possible, as best as i can tell.

Comment: no, that should't be possible. but you can translate that env file into a `/etc/profile.d/postgres.sh` on your host and add those variables to the environment section in docker-compose.yml. there would be no loss of functionality. and the "effort" to modify these variables would be the same.